# Background Image on an AdControl

Tags: windows-phone-7, xaml

Is it possible to add a background image to an AdControl? Or is it possible to place an AdControl *over* an image and give it a transparent background?

I have been trying several things to try to accomplish this - no luck so far.

Answer (score 0):

You can try putting a AdControl inside a Border Control. You can set the Image to a Border Control.

```
<Border Background="Red">
<AdControl id="adControl1" height=80 width="480" />
</Border>
```

Most of the Ads have a Transparent Background.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I tried this, but still no luck:

`<Border>
            <Border.Background>
                <ImageBrush ImageSource="xxx.png"></ImageBrush>
            </Border.Background>
            <Microsoft_Advertising_Mobile_UI:AdControl ApplicationId="xxx" AdUnitId="xxx" Height="80" Width="480" />
        </Border>`

Comment: There is no documentation YET which mentions the background of the Ads in AdControl can be transparent. I will try to get a Screengrab If I find one in the emulator. OTOH I notice that most of my Ads in my apps have a 'dark' Background.